# Function recursive calls has reached a limit

Tags: function, recursion

```
def power(n,p):
    "Return n to the power of p. Only works for positive integers"
    return n*power(n,p-1)
if __name__=="__main__":
    print(power(2,2))
```

I am using recursion in this function definition and it returns a recursion error.
Why is it doing that? and does the maximum depth mean that there is a limit on how many times I can call it ? I have only done it twice here!

Comment: Your recursion function has no exit case and will continue calling itself infinitely, or until the stack overflows (hey, that's the name of this site!)

Comment: your recursion doesn't stop - it will call `power(n, p-1)` for infinity. You have to add some stop condition to the recursion

Comment: All recursions need something called a "[base case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Base_case)", a circumstance where the answer is a known quantity rather than another recursive call.  A common base case for exponentiation is "x to the 0 is 1 for all non-zero x".

Answer (score 0):

I need a base case like below. The code was only meant to highlight the problem of calling the function forever. Got it! Thanks!!

```
def power(n,p):
    """ Return n to the power p. Works only for positive integers """
    if p==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n*power(n,p-1)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(power(2,10))
```